# Why does $\lim \frac{xy}{ \sqrt{x^4 + y^2}}$ at $(0,0)$ not exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Edit: Nvm, I think I read the notes wrong.

I'm learning multivariable calculus. My professor wanted us to prove that $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{ \sqrt{x^4 + y^2}}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

He put as an aside note that for, $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{ \sqrt{x^4 + y^2}}$, $f(0,0)$ does not exist.

Why is that? Is it because the denominator cannot be `0`?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown why isn't my square root working? I tried doing `\sqrt{x^3 + y^2}` which seems to be what the post says?

Comment: put $ around the expression

Comment: You need to enclose maths within dollar signs.

Comment: Pretty sure it does. Maybe I'm reading it wrong. It's not legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the denominator's limit does exist, and it is $0$.

---

Note that if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, then
\begin{align}
\left| \dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^4 + y^2}} \right| &= |x| \cdot
\left( \dfrac{|y|}{\sqrt{x^4 + y^2}} \right) \\
&\leq |x| \cdot 1 \\
&= |x|
\end{align}
By following this chain of reasoning, do you see how to conclude what $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ is?

Comment: Ah, I think he meant that for, $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{ \sqrt{x^4 + y^2}}$, $f(0,0)$ does not exist. That is correct right? Because the denominator cannot be 0?

Comment: yes exactly! What my argument shows is $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ exists, but $f$ is not continuous. It is only if you DEFINE $f(0,0) = 0$ that $f$ will be continuous at the origin

Answer (score 1):

The limit exists. Note that $\sqrt{x^4+y^2}$ is continuous, i. e.

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \sqrt{x^4 + y^2} = \sqrt{0^4 + 0^2} = 0.$$

Comment: Ah, I think he meant that for, $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{ \sqrt{x^4 + y^2}}$, $f(0,0)$ does not exist. That is correct right? Because the denominator cannot be 0?

Comment: @user2072374 This is of course right, $f(0,0)$ is not defined because you can't divide by $0$. What one usually does is to $\textit{define}$ a certain value of $f$ in the origin.